# Difficulties with estimation and strange fitted values for BVAR (BVAR R package)

Tags: bayesian, econometrics, vector-autoregression, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm using the BVAR package in R to estimate a Bayesian vector autoregression involving the following monthly variables:
US Capacity utilization, US Total Employees, US PCE index, and 5,10,20,30 year US yields. The yields are in levels and the rest are in 12xlogs.
I have specified the model following https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00181-016-1128-y and therefore the hierarchical prior selection procedures in Giannone, Lenza & Primiceri (2012), which the package purportedly implements.

When I attempt to estimate the model in levels, using the Minessota, sum-of-coefficients, and single-unit-root prior, as specified by the papers, the following error pops up:

```
Error in solve.default(XX + omega_inv, crossprod(X, Y) + omega_inv %*%  : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.70878e-17
```

This is strange, since BVARs are known for their proper handling of large, collinear, nonstationary variable sets. I would expect this error to pop up in a frequentist VAR, but not in this case.
If I remove the sum-of-coefficients and single-unit-root priors, which I find highly undesirable, the model does run.
The results for the Marginal Likelihood and Lambda are:

[image]

Which to my knowledge does not imply any abnormality in the procedure. However, the fitted values for the 10 year yield are:

[image]

Which makes no sense and is obviously not correct.These results are robust to the number of draws, burn-in period, and thinning.
What is going on? I'm not too familiar with Bayesian methods.